# Polymorphic function parameters/return values in C

Tags: c, polymorphism, c89

I'm working in an embedded microcontroller and I have to read/write multiple types data to Non-Volatile RAM (NVRAM).  I'd like to avoid having to write separate read/write functions for each value to store in NVRAM like this:

```
void Write_Value1(int value);
int Read_Value1(void);
void Write_Value2(unsigned long value);
unsigned long Read_Value2(void);
...
```

That is definitely cumbersome to maintain as the list of items to read/write grows. There's a couple of ways to tackle this in C++, templates for example.  Using a template I could write a `.Read()` and `.Write(T value)` function that each item to read/write would have access to.  Is there anyway to get this behavior from C? I suspect that there is some way, using some combination of void pointers and vtables.  I'd like to handle this in a more polymorphic fashion and have the function for reading/writing each item to NVRAM called in a similar fashion.

Comment: Polymorphism was one of the MAJOR additions to C++.  It is not a capability of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with void pointer and sizes:

```
void write_value (void *data, size_t size);
void* read_value (size_t size);
```

Then:

```
write_value ( (void *) &int_val, sizeof (int));
write_value ( (void *) &ulong_val, sizeof (unsigned long));

intptr = read_value (sizeof (int));
charptr = read_value (sizeof (char));
```

The `read_value` then needs to `malloc` something and return it. This might just be overhead sometimes, when you'd rather read into an automatic. Then do:

```
/* Declaration.  */
void read_value (void *data, size_t size);

/* Use.  */
read_value (&automatic_var, sizeof (automatic_var));
```

And finally, you could 'simulate' templates in [all sorts of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10950828/274261).

Answer (score 9):

You can [pretty closely] simulate C++ templates in C by using macros.

There are at least two way to do that.

---

**First method: "Rubber stamp" macros**

Define declare/define macros for your functions

```
#define DECLARE_READ_WRITE(suffix, type)\
  type Read_Value_##suffix(void);
  void Write_Value_##suffix(type val);

#define DEFINE_READ_WRITE(suffix, type)\
  type Read_Value_##suffix(void) {\
    /* your code */ \
  }\
  void Write_Value_##suffix(type val) {\
    /* your code */ \
  }
```

and then in some header file do

```
DECLARE_READ_WRITE(long, long)
DECLARE_READ_WRITE(int, int)
```

and in some implementation file

```
DEFINE_READ_WRITE(long, long)
DEFINE_READ_WRITE(int, int)
```

which will "generate" declarations and definitions for `Read_Value_int`, `Write_Value_int`,  `Read_value_long` and `Write_value_long`.

---

**Second method: Parameterized include files**

Create two header files. One for declarations (`read_write.h.template`)

```
TYPE__ CONCAT(Read_Value_, SUFFIX__)(void);
void CONCAT(Write_Value_, SUFFIX__)(TYPE__ val);
```

and one for definitions (`read_write.c.template`)

```
TYPE__ CONCAT(Read_Value_, SUFFIX__)(void)
{
  /* your code */
}

void CONCAT(Write_Value_, SUFFIX__)(TYPE__ val)
{
  /* your code */
}
```

Here `CONCAT` is a usual implementation of macro token concatenation (can/should be used in the first method as well).

And then include your "templated" code into an appropriate header file and implementation file as

```
#define TYPE__ int
#define SUFFIX__ int
#include "read_write.h.template"
#undef TYPE__
#undef SUFFIX__

#define TYPE__ long
#define SUFFIX__ long
#include "read_write.h.template"
#undef TYPE__
#undef SUFFIX__
```

The same thing in some implementation file with `read_write.c.template` header.

The latter method has an added benefit of producing debuggable code. I.e. you can step through it in the debugger, just like it typically works with C++ templates.

Comment: In case you're interested, there's a whole question dedicated to simulating templates in C: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10950828/274261

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186103/how-to-elegantly-implement-a-series-of-functions-in-different-type-versions-usin

Answer (score 3):

Returning a different type based on the target type is (nearly?) impossible with C.  You can mimic it with macros, though.  For example:

```
#define WRITE(x)  write_value(x, sizeof(x))
#define READ(x)  read_value(&x, sizeof(x))
```

Now you can write write_value() and read_value() to copy data out based on length, taking into account endianness in your internal routine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in C. However, you could use a struct approach.

```
#define T_VOID  0
#define T_INT   1
#define T_ULINT 2

typedef struct 
{
    int type;
    union 
    {            
        int a; 
        unsigned long b; 
    } my_union;
} my_struct;

void write_value(my_struct *s)
{
    switch (s->type) 
    {
        case T_VOID:
        // do something
        break;
        case T_INT: 
        // do something with s->my_union.a
        break;
        case T_ULINT: 
        // do something with s->my_union.b
        break;
    }
}
```

In the same fashion, `read_value` would return a `my_struct` pointer.

Comment: This is very elegant. I was hoping to avoid a huge switch statement, but the union does clean it up a bit. I feel like there's a gotcha somewhere in using a union when I want to Read/Write more complex types (stucts for example) or when Endianness comes into play.

Comment: I would use an unnamed Union, [http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html), so to avoid typing the pointless union name

Comment: The construct is known as a "smart union". The other way would be to have all structs starting with the typetag, but will cuase more casting to be needed) I would *not* use an unnamed union, since it is not legal in ansi C / C89 ; is a (Microsoft) "extension". (maybe legalized by C99. Wouln't that be ironic?)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Posix `read` and `write` functions and just do something similar:

```
void read(int address, void * data, int size);
void write(int address, const void * data, int size);
```

Then later:

```
read(address, &x, sizeof(x));
write(address, &x, sizeof(x));
```