# A C function similar to C++ generic

Tags: c, arrays, function, generics

I want to implement a function like a `c++` generic. Apart from integers, the parameters should also support char type, and any other types as well.

```
void function t(int a[],int len);
```

How to implement this in C  language?

Comment: In C++ you have templates. In C, the closest thing you have to that is macros... eek.

Comment: C does not have templates.  What do you want this function to do, specifically?  Please edit your question to include a concrete example.

Comment: `void*` is what you need to use.  And a modicum of clever (but careful!) programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymorphic function parameters/return values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397856/polymorphic-function-parameters-return-values-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have templates in C like you do C++ you have a few different options, which may be suitable depending on the task at hand:

- Using the pre-processor and creating a basic macro, such as your basic `MIN`/`MAX` type macro that simply wraps a few `<` and `>` operations.
- Writing different versions of the function for specific data types - `function_int(int...)`, `function_char(char...)`, etc.
- Writing a generic function which takes in data as a `void*`, not knowing the implementation details, and a function pointer which is called by the function which acts on the data and does know how to operate on this data.

  In this case, look at a function like `bsearch`, where the search key and array are of type `void *`, and a comparison function is passed for a specific type of data:

  ```
  void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
  ```

  The comparison function is the only piece of code that needs to know the type of the data, so you only need to write the generic part of your function once. However, you do still need to write a function for each data type that you want to operate on, as with the point above.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technique that I believe was described in the book [C Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672318962). The book probably has something a little more elegant than what I am able to reproduce from memory.

You can have an include file like this:

```
/* function.tmpl */
#ifndef FUNCTION
#define FUNCTION_PASTE(X,Y) X ## _ ## Y
#define FUNCTION(X) FUNCTION_PASTE(function, X)
#endif

void FUNCTION(TYPE) (TYPE a[], int len) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Then you can include it like this:

```
#define TYPE int
#include "function.tmpl"
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE double
#include "function.tmpl"
#undef TYPE
```

And call functions like this:

```
int a[4];
FUNCTION(int)(a, 4);

double b[5];
FUNCTION(double)(b, 5);
```

Comment: Wow, wonderful. I will play with that. I suspect that the typeof(http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) operator can be a lot useful here.

Comment: Ignore the typeof comment. It does not works as I expected.. this operator is limited to assigning only: `typeof(a) foo = ..;`

Comment: @Jack: I didn't think of it myself. It is described in a book which I had thumbed through a long time ago. I've updated the answer with the book title. Thanks for reminding me. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this in C is to pass a void*. But then you need an extra information to actually do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
enum data_type { CHAR_TYPE, INT_TYPE };

void function t(void* buf, size_t len, enum data_type type) {
    int*  int_ary;
    char* char_ary;

    if (type == CHAR_TYPE) {
        char_ary* = buf;
        ...
    } else if (type == INT_TYPE) {
        int_ary* = buf;
        ...
    }
}
```

It's hackish and error-prone, but it could work.  It's not exactly like C++ in that it's one unified function instead of a separate version for each type.