# Is there a case where including the same header twice is actually helpful?

Tags: c++, c

Creating header guards for my h/hpp files has always been standard practice for me, but I wonder, why is it even possible to include de same file twice? Is there a case where you actually need unprotected headers?

Comment: Because some headers include other headers, to gain access to the types defined in them.  And the original C design didn't include implicit "protection" (nor did most C compilers add it).  There are some cases where including code multiple times may be useful, but those are not conventional "headers".

Comment: (Objective-C has the `#import` directive, and other languages have `includeonce` or some such, so there's no reason this couldn't be done -- the developers of C just never got around to it.)

Comment: (It is worthwhile to consider that the original "assemblers" were called that because they "assembled" multiple include files to make a program.  This back when "closed" subroutines were considered wimpy.  Thus the concept of `#include` working the way it does was consistent with prior practice and seemed "natural".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Parameterized" header files can be used to simulate C++-ish-style templates in C. In such cases the header file will depend on a number of macros ("template parameters"). It will generate different code depending on the actual "value" of these macros.

So, the typical usage of such header would look as a sequence of "template parameter" macro definitions followed by the `#include` directive, followed by another sequence of "template parameter" macro definitions followed by the same `#include`, and so on.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186396/187690

When using this technique you will see header files without any include guards or header files with include guards that cover only a portion of the file.

Comment: Also simpler example: you never know how a "contrived" user might have written his (legacy or not) code: http://pastebin.com/YSzLwqay (although I agree that this is just horrible)

Answer (score 7):

Stuff like Boost.PP does lots of tricks by including headers multiple times. It essentially allows for primitive forms of loops.

Also, [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) are designed to be included multiple times.

Comment: +1 for the Wikipedia X-Macros link (even though the SO FAQs frown on it).

Answer (score 7):

In C:

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

...code using active asserts...

#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

...code using disabled asserts...
```

Rinse and repeat.  The analogue in C++ uses the header `<cassert>` instead.

So, sometimes there are reasons to include a header twice.  Not often, but there are reasons to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Cases like these are rare, and when they do exist, a re-design is better suited anyway. One I can think of is headers that amass declarations:

```
//functions.h
virtual void foo();
virtual void goo();

//classes.h
class A : public Base
{
    #include "functions.h"
};

class B : public Base
{
    #include "functions.h"
};
```

This wouldn't work if `functions.h` had include guards, but then again, this is pretty awkward code...

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are writing your own template array wrapper (elements are pointers) for your tiny engine where array can either be:

- dynamic or static
- indexes/order matters or not
- you can delete an element (not just remove from the array) outside the array or inside

so with this you can either create one class where all this handled but it would always check for what we can or cannot do. best is to create separate classes but here we have so much same code between them you could (if not careful) either make a mistake in one of them functions plus adding a new function would be slower.

so best is to take use of the "Parameterized" header files (as AnT stated) and simply create classes like

- Cl_Array_Dy, Cl_Array_DyIn, Cl_Array_DyDel, Cl_Array_DyInDel
- Cl_Array_St, Cl_Array_StIn, Cl_Array_StDel, Cl_Array_StInDel

code example:

// TestDfM.h

```
#ifndef TEST_DFM_H
#   define TEST_DFM_H

    // first we need to make sure neither of these is defined
#   ifdef Df_ARG1
#       undef Df_ARG1
#   endif
#   ifdef Cl_First
#       undef Cl_First
#   endif
#   ifdef Cl_Second
#       undef Cl_Second
#   endif
#   ifdef Df_FIRST
#       undef Df_FIRST
#   endif
#   ifdef Df_SECOND
#       undef Df_SECOND
#   endif
#   ifdef TEST_DF_H
#       undef TEST_DF_H
#   endif

    // we need this
#   define Df_FIRST 1
#   define Df_SECOND 2

    // first class creation
#   define Df_CLASS Df_FIRST
#   define Df_ARRAY Cl_First
#   include "TestDf.h"

    // cleanup (after 1st)
#   undef Df_CLASS
#   undef Df_ARRAY

    // second class creation
#   define Df_CLASS Df_SECOND
#   define Df_ARRAY Cl_Second
#   define Df_ARG1
#   include "TestDf.h"

    // cleanup (after 2st)
#   undef Df_CLASS
#   undef Df_ARRAY
#   undef Df_ARG1

    // so we theoretically cannot include TestDf.h anymore (anywhere)
#   define TEST_DF_H

#endif // TEST_DFM_H
```

// TestDf.h

```
// nothing to do here if the main header for this was not included
// also we should only call this inside the main header
#if defined(TEST_DFM_H) && !defined(TEST_DF_H)
#   include "../Includes.h"

    class Df_ARRAY {
    public:
        int m_shared;

#   ifndef Df_ARG1
        Df_ARRAY(int in_shared=0) { m_shared= in_shared; }
        void f_info() { printf("out: %d\n", m_shared); }
#   else
        int m_x;
        Df_ARRAY(int in_shared=0, int in_x= 7) { m_shared= in_shared; m_x= in_x; }
        void f_info() { printf("out: %d [also has %d]\n", m_shared, m_x); }
#   endif

#   if Df_CLASS == Df_FIRST
        void f_class() { printf("1st\n"); }
#   elif Df_CLASS == Df_SECOND
        void f_class() { printf("2nd\n"); }
#   endif
    };

#endif // TEST_DFM_H
```

// Main.cpp

```
#include "Array/TestDfM.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Cl_First a(6);
    Cl_Second b(2);
    a.f_class(); // 1st
    b.f_class(); // 2nd
    a.f_info(); // out: 6
    b.f_info(); // out: 2 [also has 7]
    return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Header files are just textually included whenever they are encountered. There isn't any real reason why they can't be included more than once. If headers are only used for declaration and no definitions (and no declarations of templates with default arguments) there isn't even anything problematic with including them more than once.

That said `<cassert>` is the canonical example of including a file more than once: You can change the definition of `NDEBUG` and get different behavior from the `assert()` macro within one translation unit.

Now having something like `include_once` which includes a file just once turns out to be not as trivial as people tend to think. Here is an example where it isn’t clear how often `foo.h` should be included:

```
#include_once "foo.h"
#include_once "./foo.h"
#include_once "bar/foo.h"
```

Assuming `include_once` includes each file just once, how often should `foo.h` be included? All three files can easily refer to the same physical file but this may not readily be visible, e.g., because one is a link to another one. It seems best to give the control to the programmer how can control how often they end up being used.

Comment: Other languages do it easily, why would it be less trivial to c/c++ do the same?

Comment: @Luke B.: Which other language uses textual inclusion (rather than some sort of a midule system) and solves the problem (portably and correctly)?

Comment: Now you're just moving the goalposts, what's so hard about checking the files entire path before deciding? What textual inclusion or not has to do with that?

Comment: @LukeB.: I'm not moving any goal posts! I stated what C and C++ are doing and need to cope with and I'm genuinely unaware of another system which does exactly the same and solves the problem of knowing which files it needs to include just once and which doesn't. One part of the problem is that the same file (or the same content) can be reached using multiple paths and depending on how a file is included the compiler finds a different instance but they all have the same content. Determining the location is not sufficient nor is determining a file identification (like an inode).

Comment: Autohotkey has a `#include` which will include a file once only. It also has `#includeAgain` which forces another inclusion of the file.